# What is the easiest way in python to modify linux config file?

Tags: python

I have some python scripts that configure linux computers. One of the tasks is to modify a configuration file for subversion. This file, `~/.subversion/servers` is very simple and looks like this:

```
# store-passwords = no
# store-plaintext-passwords = no
# store-ssl-client-cert-pp = no
# store-ssl-client-cert-pp-plaintext = no
... lots of other options ...
```

The task of my script is to find a required option, for example `store-plaintext-passwords` and to set it to specified value, for example `yes`. The problem is: the script can run multiple times on same machine, so if it is run first time this option can be just commented, if it is run second time it can be uncommented and set to `yes`, third run can point out that it is uncommented - but set to `no` etc. Currently i have a rather complex code that search file for the string, splits it for comment/name/value, uncomments it if needed, changes value if needed and replaces it. Maybe it's an easier way possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ~/.subversion/servers file is in INI format.

So you can use the ConfigParser for implementing whatever you need.

http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

Comment: ConfigParser is good - but how will it handle comments? I don't need the resulting file to be stripped of all commented fields ^_^

Comment: nobody cares about comments in auto-generated or manipulated files

Comment: @Eye of Hell - ConfigParser supports `#` and `;` style comments. So you are good to go here. It wont strip the comments.

Comment: @Senthil Kumaran: `configparser` ignores comments; you lose all comments if you write config file using the module. https://ideone.com/3n3Vj https://ideone.com/sGVnF

Comment: J.F. Sebastian - Thanks for pointing that out. It is still an open bug here: http://bugs.python.org/issue1410680